# Is it ok to use anyio.sleep_forever() to prevent a process from exiting?

Tags: python, python-anyio

In my case I am registering consumers on aio-pika:

```
async def on_message(message: AbstractIncomingMessage) -> None:
    async with message.process():
        print(f" [x] Received message {message!r}")
        print(f"     Message body is: {message.body!r}")


async def main() -> None:
    # Perform connection
    connection = await connect_robust("amqp://guest:guest@localhost/")

    async with connection:
        # Creating a channel
        channel = await connection.channel()

        # Declaring queue
        queue = await channel.declare_queue(
            "task_queue",
            durable=True,
        )

        # Start listening the queue with name 'task_queue'
        await queue.consume(on_message)

        # Prevent process from exiting
        await anyio.sleep_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    anyio.run(main)
```

I can't see any problem, but if feels like a hack and that should have another way, a proper way.